# Eclipse java won't use import

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I am very new to the world of programming and just decided to try and take it up in the last few weeks. I have learned most of what I know(which is not much) so far from a book I bought on java programming. So the problem may be basic, but I have no clue.

Anyways. I just installed Eclipse 4.2.2 and I tried to make a simple program. It was a program that displayed a list of numbers. In the program I inclueded "import static java.lang.System.out" and "import java.util.Scanner". I wrote the program right but it kept on returning the same errors:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
>
> Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
>
> Syntax error on token "]", invalid (
>
> Syntax error, insert "]" to complete ArrayAccess
>
> Syntax error, insert ")" to complete SingleMemberAnnotation
>
> Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader
>
> at countto.main(countto.java:6)

So commented out the imports and used the full statements instead and it worked fine.
I fairly certain I was using the imports properly because I wrote the exact same program on a IDE I have on my phone called "Sand", and it used the import parts just fine.

Could someone please help me?

I don't know it this helps but this is the code:

```
public class countto {

import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int again = 1, countto, count;

    while (again == 1) {

        out.println("What number do you want to count to?");

        countto = keyboard.nextInt();

        out.println();

        for (count = 1; count <= countto; count++) {

            out.println(count);

        }

        out.println();

        out.println("Again?");

        out.println("1:yes   2:no");

        again = keyboard.nextInt();

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Isn't your eclipse showing any red line marks over few lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your imports before your class.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class countto {..}
```

Comment: And capitalise class names as well!

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. I had learned that I was supposed to do that but I completely forgot.

Answer (score 0):

If you press control-shift-o that is the shortcut for 'optimize imports' and eclipse will try to properly set up your imports for you.  Even if this does work, it is NEVER a substitute for properly understanding how to use the import statement, knowing what to import and why.  :-)  If this does fix your problem, your next task should be to look at what the IDE did with your statements and determine the difference between what worked and what did not.